# I get this error when I use view component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am new to ASP.NET Core. I get this error when I use view component. Thank you for your help

> InvalidOperationException: Method 'Invoke' of view component 'UI.ViewComponents.NavbarViewComponent' cannot return a Task.

This is my code

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> Invoke()
{
    var settings = await _db.Settings.ToListAsync();
    return View(settings);
}
```

And in view :

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Navbar")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are returning a task from the View Component, you should use the InvokeAsync , asynchronous method instead of the sync method. Your Code Should look like this :

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
  var settings = await _db.Settings.ToListAsync();
  return View(settings);
}
```